# Can't add Autofac to ServiceCollection in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

I want to add Autofac to .Net Core application. 
I've tried to do all steps from [Autofac:Getting started tutorial](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start-with-configurecontainer), I've installed `Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, have updated `Program` class, but can't add autofac as in example.

Get error

> Error CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddAutofac' and no extension method 'AddAutofac' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Reinstall nuget package, clean & rebuild solution, close VS - things which doesn't help.

---

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac()) //here is problem
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
  }
}
```

---

Version of Autofac - 4.6.2
Version of Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection - 4.2.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding `using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;`

```
using System.IO;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace App
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac()) 
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: pfff... so simple... I've tried to add `using Autofac;` instead of this... Thanks

Comment: @demo - do note that in VS2015+, you can hover over a missing reference and it will display a light bulb. Click the down arrow next to the light bulb and it will show a command indicating the proper using directive to add (and will do it in one click).

Comment: @NightOwl888, I'm aware of this but in this case it advice only to "Change signature"